# How to give fixed space after a word in python

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
listOfWordsWithCount = [{'word':'me', 'count':2}, {'word':'you', 'count':2}, {'word':'weldone', 'count':1}, {'word':'highest', 'count':1},{'word':'to', 'count':1}, {'word':'greetings', 'count':3};
```

My Desired Output:

```
me         2
you        2
weldone    1
highest    1
to         1
greetings  3
```

My Code,

```
for w in listOfWordsWithCount:
    print(w['word'] + "        " + str(w['count']))
```

My Output,

```
me     2
you     2
weldone    1
highest    1
to    1
greetings     3
```

I want to put a fixed space after every word, Can anyone help me figure it out.